# Enums are implemented internally as integers. Then why does this give an error?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, integer

The code is :

//Correct

```
enum StudentNames
{
KENNY, // 0
KYLE, // 1
STAN, // 2
BUTTERS, // 3
CARTMAN, // 4
WENDY, // 5
MAX_STUDENTS // 6
};

int main()
{
int testScores[MAX_STUDENTS]; // allocate 6 integers
testScores[STAN] = 76; // still works

return 0;
}
```

//Incorrect : Gives compile time error

```
enum class StudentNames
{
KENNY, // 0
KYLE, // 1
STAN, // 2
BUTTERS, // 3
CARTMAN, // 4
WENDY, // 5
MAX_STUDENTS // 6
};

int main()
{
int testScores[StudentNames::MAX_STUDENTS]; // allocate 6 integers
testScores[StudentNames::STAN] = 76;
}
```

Then it's corrected again as:

```
namespace StudentNames
{
enum StudentNames
{
    KENNY, // 0
    KYLE, // 1
    STAN, // 2
    BUTTERS, // 3
    CARTMAN, // 4
    WENDY, // 5
    MAX_STUDENTS // 6
    };
 }

int main()
{
int testScores[StudentNames::MAX_STUDENTS]; // allocate 6 integers
testScores[StudentNames::STAN] = 76;
}
```

Since, Enums are implemented internally as integers. Why is there an error in the second case?

And how does adding a namespace correct it ?

Comment: i didn't get the use of namespace StudentNames

Comment: I haven't written this code. It's from learncpp.com @Ajay.

Comment: Hmm , please read the ans of rici i think what he try to saying is correct as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

`enum class` is not the same as `enum`.

If you have an `enum class`, then you have values which are not of type `int` (although they have an integer representation). You cannot implicitly convert them to any other type, not even another `enum`. That's a Good Thing; it lets you defined type-safe enumerations. (If you want to use them as `int`, you can use an explicit conversion.)

So it's not the introduction of a namespace which makes the second one compile. It's the absence of `class` in the `enum` declaration.

If you really want to use values of an `enum class` as `int`s, you need an explicit conversion:

```
int main() {
  int testScores[int(StudentNames::MAX_STUDENTS)]; // allocate 6 integers
  testScores[int(StudentNames::STAN)] = 76;
  // ...
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend using that code, since the whole point of `enum class` is to indicate that the enumeration values *should not* be used as integers.

(There are reasons to do the conversion, but they should be rare. For example, while you could use a `std::map` indexed by the `enum class`, it would be a bit inefficient. On the other hand, a typical `enum class` has few enough members that the inefficiency might not matter as much as clarity. Note that you cannot use a `std::unordered_map`, because while `enum class` values are comparable they are not hashable.)

Comment: You should generally refrain from using C style casts. The correct cast to use here would be `static_cast<int>()`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I didn't use a C style cast. I used an explicit type converstion in functional form, as per 5.2.3. The C style cast has different parenthesization. Indeed, `static_cast<int>` would work, but the `int` constructor is perfectly valid `C++`, and I don't see why it would be problematic in this usage.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: On the other hand, I don't think I sufficiently discouraged the idiom. Normally, you simply shouldn't convert `enum class` values to `int`s. I added that observation ot the answer.